# group articles by day in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to group articles in each day, image blow will show you how it looks like now

[image]

I have 3 records that have their date on top right of them, but as you can see each one of them is separated, I want to show record on this date in one group and tomorrow if I added more records shows on that date group,
my codes:

Models.py:

```
class Form(models.Model):

food_type = models.ForeignKey(FoodTypes, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

calorie = models.CharField(max_length=50)

protein = models.ForeignKey(Protein, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

carbohydrate = models.ForeignKey(Carbohydrate, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

drinks = models.ForeignKey(Drinks, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

fruits = models.CharField(max_length=50)
note = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

views.py:

```
def requests(request):
lists = Form.objects.all().order_by('-date')
context = {
    'lists': lists
}
return render(request, 'form/requests_list.html', context)
```

template file:

```
    {% for lists in lists %}

<div class="req-list">
<h6>{{ lists.date }}</h6>
   <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">نوع غذا</th>
      <th scope="col">کالری</th>
      <th scope="col">پروتئین</th>
      <th scope="col">کربوهیدرات</th>
      <th scope="col">نوشیدنی</th>
      <th scope="col">میوه</th>
      <th scope="col">توضیحات</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ lists.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ lists.food_type }}</td>
      <td>{{ lists.calorie }}</td>
      <td>@{{ lists.protein }}</td>
        <td>@{{ lists.carbohydrate }}</td>
        <td>@{{ lists.drinks }}</td>
        <td>@{{ lists.fruits }}</td>
        <td>@{{ lists.note }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [{% ifchanged %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986324/4151233

Following code is not tested:

```
{% for lists in lists %}
    {% ifchanged lists.date %}
        <div class="req-list">
            <h6>{{ lists.date }}</h6>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">نوع غذا</th>
                        <th scope="col">کالری</th>
                        <th scope="col">پروتئین</th>
                        <th scope="col">کربوهیدرات</th>
                        <th scope="col">نوشیدنی</th>
                        <th scope="col">میوه</th>
                        <th scope="col">توضیحات</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                {% endifchanged %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ lists.id }}</th>
                        <td>{{ lists.food_type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ lists.calorie }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ lists.protein }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ lists.carbohydrate }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ lists.drinks }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ lists.fruits }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ lists.note }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% ifchanged lists.date %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did work, Thanks a lot, but it would be like this

    {% ifchanged lists.date %}
<h6>{{ lists.date }}</h6> 
    {% endifchanged %}

only 1 ifchanged for lists.date